# How can cookieless session be set or not depending on the domain of the request in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iframe, session-state, cookieless

I have an MVC 3 application that services requests on two different domains. Requests to firstdomain.com come from an iframe, requests to seconddomain.com come from a normal browser window. I need to use cookieless session in the iframe, but want to keep cookie-based session in the normal browser.

Normally the session type is determined in the web.config by setting the following:

```
<system.web>
   ...
   <sessionState cookieless="UseUri"/>
   ...
</system.web>
```

But this applies to every request regardless of the domain. It would be possible to have two copies of the site on the server, one for each domain, and each having a different value for the sessionState cookieless setting, but I would like to avoid that for a number of reasons. Is there a way to toggle this feature depending on the domain of the request while running a single instance of the web application?

Answer (score 0):

You could split the two into separate projects, each with their own web.config.  That is one thought that would be better than two separate instances running.

Just out of curiousity, why cookies?  Cache or Session would plausibly be better.

Comment: It is a cross-domain iframe and some browsers don't like having their cookies on that plate. :)

Comment: Ah, I see.  Stupid browsers not liking cookies on their plate, lol.